# MySQL cached prepared statements for performance

Tags: mysql, c, prepared-statement

Are prepared statements not cached by MySQL if you call `mysql_stmt_close`?

I want MySQL to cache commonly used statements. The problem is that I don't know all of the details of how MySQL handles caching statements.

For example, would it be better to hang onto the `mysql_stmt` pointer and just continually bind different parameters and execute it?

Or, would that only save me C memory allocations because MySQL actually caches statements based on query matching (or something), and it has nothing to do with how many times I `mysql_stmt_prepare` and `mysql_stmt_close` or how many times I `mysql_connect`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you issue a [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/statement-caching.html), MySQL prepares some things like parsing and executions plans, so when you later bind the actual parameters, it doesn't need to do this (again). The preparation usually requires only some ms. If that's relevant will depend on the total execution time of your query, and you can obviously only save time if you run it more than once (but you don't lose time either if you just run it once). That being said, using prepared statements even if you just run it once is a [standard security measure](https://xkcd.com/327/).

The prepared statement is stored on the server and requires (a little bit of) memory. It is freed when you close it and is not cached afterwards. It's also specific to a connection, so different connections will allocate their own memory for the same query.

You can keep several prepared statements active. There is actually an upper limit for the total count of open prepared statements (given by [max_prepared_stmt_count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_prepared_stmt_count)), but it will depend on how many users are using your app if that (and the memory allocated by them, which is still usually neglectable) is relevant for your consideration.

There are some practical implication when holding long-time prepared statements, the most important regarding that prepared statements are lost when you lose the connection (either by accident or if you close it intentionally). This may or may not complicate your code (to e.g. reinitialize your statements on connection loss). It also forces you to keep your connection open, and although MySQL usually doesn't need many resources to keep sleeping connection open, you may or may not want that. Also, this will basically prevent you from using connection pools (unless they support that), as you cannot give a connection back to the pool without losing the prepared statement (although this is usually less relevant for a c-application).

This is the behaviour of the standard c mysql api (as your syntax suggested). If you use alternative tools, this behaviour can of course be different. As an example, the [java driver](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/stmtcach.htm#i1069942) *does* (optionally) cache statements on `.close`. But it basically does that by simply not actually closing it (via the api), and handling things like reinitializing on connection loss and such internally. This implies there can be some use for such an (application side) cache, and while I am not aware of a c alternative for that, it is certainly possible (and should not be to complicated) to implement that (and it's likely someone already did).

And a last note, as you may be looking for that: Until MySQL 8, there was a [query cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html) to cache the result of a specific sql query. If you run a query twice with the exact same code (with the exact same parameters) and if there were no updates to the tables involves (and if the cache was enabled and the resultset was not too big), MySQL would fetch the result from that cache without the need to reexecute the query. It's only closely related to prepared statements, and transparent to the application (you would not need to change anything), but might be relevant in the context of caching.